# PIL selftests fine and can import __imaging, but still "Imaging is not installed" error

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I'm running OS X 10.7.5 and have been trying for weeks to get PIL working.

It installs and compiles fine, passes its selftest, and I can import __imaging without any errors.

However, when I try and use the scikit-image reading and writing functionality, which depends on PIL, I still get the classic "The imaging C module is not installed" error.

Does anyone have any idea how to debug this? I am stumped.

Comment: Have you tried [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) instead? It's the friendly PIL fork that has fixed *many* packaging problems, as well as other bugs.

Comment: Explicit [Mac OS X installation instructions](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#mac-os-x-installation) are provided, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters do you know if it's been tested with scikit-image? Thanks

Comment: @Louise: Pillow is a better PIL. Unless Scikit-image relies on specific PIL bugs, it'll work.

Comment: @Louise: In fact, the Scikit-image project [names Pillow first, PIL second](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html#optional-requirements).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It's a fork of PIL and has fixed many bugs and is [actively developed](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/commits/master), unlike PIL.

Mac OS X installation instructions can be [found here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#mac-os-x-installation):

> **Note:** You *do not* need to install all of the external libraries to get
> Pillow’s basics to work.

> **We do not provide binaries for OS X, so
> you’ll need XCode to install Pillow.** (XCode 4.2 on 10.6 will work with
> the Official Python binary distribution. Otherwise, use whatever XCode
> you used to compile Python.)
>
> The easiest way to install the prerequisites is via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh). After
> you install Homebrew, run:
>
> ```
> $ brew install libtiff libjpeg webp little-cms2
> ```

> If you’ve built your
> own Python, then you should be able to install Pillow using:
>
> ```
> $ pip install Pillow
> ```

Also, it's best to avoid OS X's system Python and use the Homebrew version.